# C# The SelectCommand property has not been initialized before calling 'Fill'. in WinForm

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I'm trying to programmatically populate DataGridView in my Windows Form with DB data, but I'm obviously doing something wrong.

```
namespace UDDKT
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        SqlConnection connection;
        string connectionString;

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter DaDavaoci = new SqlDataAdapter();
        SqlDataAdapter DaAkcije = new SqlDataAdapter();

        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["UDDKT.Properties.Settings.UDDKTConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        }

        public SqlCommand SlctDavaoci { get; private set; }

        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PopuniDgDavaoci();
        }

        private void PopuniDgDavaoci()
        {
            using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Davaoci", connection))
            {
                DaDavaoci.SelectCommand = SlctDavaoci;
                DaDavaoci.Fill(ds, "TblDavaoci");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to run it, it highlights DaDavaoci and says: Exception Unhandled System.InvalidOperationException: 'The SelectCommand property has not been initialized before calling 'Fill'.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong SqlAdapter.

At the top you create an adapter named `DaDavoci`:

```
SqlDataAdapter DaDavaoci = new SqlDataAdapter();
```

But you are passing no CommandText and no Connection.

At the bottom you create a new adapter named `adapter` (with connection and commandtext). But then you are using the adapter from the top again which still has no commandtext and no connection.

```
using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Davaoci", connection))
{
    DaDavaoci.SelectCommand = SlctDavaoci;
    DaDavaoci.Fill(ds, "TblDavaoci");
}
```

You should use the adapter you have created which contains a commandtext and a connection like this

```
using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Davaoci", connection))
{
    adapter.SelectCommand = SlctDavaoci;
    adapter.Fill(ds, "TblDavaoci");
}
```

I don't know exactly what you are trying to do, but i think the initialization of the two adapters on the top of your code dont make sense (at least to me). I would not store the connection nor the adapter in a classvariable, but instead create new ones when you need them. (If you are using the using-keyword, the instace you create is gonna be disposed after the end of the using-scope. So either use using and create new instances where you need them or make it a classvariable and not use using)

Comment: Thanks mate, you helped a lot. The solution was so simple but I couldn't see it at the time.

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying this section of code to something like this:

```
string queryString = "SELECT * FROM Davaoci";

private DataSet PopuniDgDavaoci(DataSet ds, string connectionString, string queryString)
{
    using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
         SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
         adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
         adapter.Fill(ds);
    }

    return ds;
}
```

Then you can attach your dataset to your grid.

Something like:

```
MyGrid.DataSource = ds;
```

More info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 0):

It should be corrected because there is nothing in sql command

```
using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) 
{
 using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Davaoci",connection ))
       {
            SqlCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter);
            DataTable table = new DataTable
            {
                Locale = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
            };
            dataAdapter.Fill(table);
            YourDataGridView.DataSource = table;
        }
}
```

For example please go through this 
[How to: Bind data to the Windows Forms DataGridView control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-bind-data-to-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did to solve my issue:

```
namespace UDDKT
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter DaDavaoci = new SqlDataAdapter();
        SqlDataAdapter DaAkcije = new SqlDataAdapter();
        SqlConnection cs = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\UDDKT.mdf;Integrated Security=True");

        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlCommand SlctDavaoci = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Davaoci", cs);
            DaDavaoci.SelectCommand = SlctDavaoci;
            DaDavaoci.Fill(ds, "TblDavaoci");

            SqlCommand SlctAkcije = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM AkcijaDDK", cs);
            DaAkcije.SelectCommand = SlctAkcije;
            DaAkcije.Fill(ds, "TblAkcije");

            DgDavaoci.DataSource = ds.Tables["TblDavaoci"];
            DgAkcije.DataSource = ds.Tables["TblAkcije"];
        }
    }
}
```